# Azure Data Flow expression : Unable to parse

Tags: azure-data-factory, expressionbuilder

**Context :**

- Inside Azure Data Factory, I have a pipeline which contains a "Foreach" activity.
- I'm trying to write an expression for its "Items" setting.

In the expression builder, I have entered this :

```
@if(not(empty(activity('GetReplies').output.resultSets)), activity('GetReplies').output.resultSets[0].rows, array([]))
```

To make it more readable for you, I'm breaking it into several lines here (but not in the expression builder) :

```
@if(
   //condition
   not(empty(activity('GetReplies').output.resultSets)),
   //true
   activity('GetReplies').output.resultSets[0].rows, 
   //false
   array([])
)
```

*Note: The idea is to check if activity "GetReplies" produced a set of items. If yes, return it. If not, return an empty array.*

**There is no error highlighted in the expression builder.** The pipeline gets saved, validated, published.

**Problem :**
When I run the pipeline, I get an error "Unable to parse" on this expression.

[image]

Troubleshooting :
I've tried with the simplest possible expression I could find to generate a set of items :

```
@array([])
```

...It still complains that the expression can't be parsed... (same error message)

What's the issue there???

Answer (score 0):

There were **two kinds** of answers in there:

1. Be very careful with **unwanted carriage returns**. For example if your expression builder contains this :
   [image]

...then it's not correct because of the carriage return before the leading '@'

2. Some **typing** problems are not caught, and later deemed "parse errors" at runtime, which is misleading.
   *Note: In this case, it was the use of `array([])` because function `array` is not supposed to take an array but a single value in parameter.*

Replacing `array([])` with `json("[]")` fixed the issue.